# Beamer: Reset headline/titlebar to split presentation in two

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I will have to present two research papers. I would like to keep them in a single presentation but reset the headline when I switch from the first to the second.

Is there a way to do it?

I am using the Berlin theme.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, I edited your question a bit to be more consise. You're fre to roll it back if you don't like it. Is it not necessary to write "hi" and "thank you" on SX

Answer (score 4):

One can split the presentation into several `\part`s. Each part will have an independent navigation bar at the top of the frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}

\part{first paper}  

\section{test}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\part{next paper}

\section{bla}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```